# get nested element content with simpleDOM

Tags: php, html, simpledom

How do I get `ext_link` content with simple DOM from the following DOM?

```
...
<td class="player">
<img src="Web/Images/Players/33/45d5652.png" />
<a class="ext_link" target="_blank" href="2017-18/Player/7124151">Michel Jordan</a>
</td>
...
```

I tried with:

```
foreach($html->find('td.player')->find('a.ext_link') as $element) {
       echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
}
```

and also with:

```
foreach($html->find('td.player')->children(2) as $element) {
       echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
}
```

But both attempts didn't work.

**Note** that I can't do `$html->find('a.ext_link')` because there are other `a` elements with `ext_link` class in the document. I only need the ones inside the td with class `player`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can [find](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find)  all the (nested) children like this:

```
foreach($html->find('td[class=player] a[class="ext_link"]') as $element){
    echo $element->innertext();
}
```

If you only want the direct children, this can be an option:

```
foreach($html->find('td[class=player]') as $element){
    foreach ($element->childNodes() as $childNode) {
        if ($childNode->nodeName() === "a") {
            echo $childNode->innertext();
        }
    }
}
```